# .htaccess 301 redirect to site B with referrer from site A

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to make the following redirection with .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 pageA.php to https://newSite/pageB.php?referrer=pageA.php
```

I need the pageA.php to be redirected to another site along with a referrer from the origin site containing pageA.php

Is there a way to do this in htaccess?

Comment: The referrer is determined by the client, you can not “fake” it. What do you need it for anyway, considering how unreliable it is in general?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
RewriteRule ^/pageA.php https://newSite/pageB.php?referrer=pageA.php  [R=301,L]
```